# What does Gazebo use Random number generator for?

Tags: gazebo-tutorial

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In this [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=random_numbers&cat=math) on Random Numbers, It says that

> Gazebo makes use of a random number
> generator. By default its seed is set
> to PID But we can manually set the
> seed too
>
> for example
>
> Gazebo can be initialized with a
> random number seed on the command line
> using the --seed argument:
>
> ```
> gazebo --seed <integer>
> ```

I tried the command `gazebo --seed 9`
Well, it opened gazebo , but I do not know what was changed or what was different.

I can't understand the tutorial. What is the random number for?? What does gazebo use it for? What if I change it?

I'm quite new in Gazebo, please help to explain.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17056/what-does-gazebo-use-random-number-generator-for?/) by [alienmon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2835/alienmon/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 28 on 2017-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It's used by gazebo/ignition math library for generating random numbers. For example, the rubble plugin uses the random number generator for creating rubbles, and camera noise model uses it to generate random gaussian noise, etc.

It's also passed down to the physics engines if they need it, e.g. in ODE we call `dRandSetSeed`

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2017-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2835/alienmon/) on 2017-08-21**:
what is the meaning of specifying integer e.g. 9 as seed? Other than things you mentioned, the gazebo simulation will behave the same?

**Comment by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) on 2017-08-22**:
here's an answer on the seed does: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914595/what-is-a-seed-in-terms-of-generating-a-random-number

The fork of ODE in gazebo removes a lot of randomness in order to provide a more deterministic behavior.  but to be safe, you can set the same seed every time to get repeatable simulations

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2835/alienmon/) on 2017-08-23**:
@iche033 Thank you for your answer. Just to confirm..So a seed is where the random number starts from. Random number is used by gazebo for e.g. generating noise, rubbles ,etec?

**Comment by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) on 2017-08-23**:
yes that's correct